# ElasticSearch: Find geo_shape nearest to given coordinates point

Tags: elasticsearch, gis

I'm trying to do following task using ElasticSearch:
Objective:Find route closest to given location
Steps:
 1. Index several routes from certain source to destination as set of geo co-ordinates in index called 'routes'.
 2. Find nearest route to given coordinates
 3. Get nearest point on the route in step 2

Please refer illustrative map screenshot:
[image: Index coordinates of route in step 1]

-- Curl requests for Step 1:
a.

```
    curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/routes' -d '{"mappings": {
     "route": {
       "properties": {
         "name": {
           "type": "string"
         },
         "location": {
          "type": "geo_shape"
        }
       }
     }
   }
 }'
```

b.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/routes/1' -d '{"name": "Indira Nagar", "path": {
     "type": "polygon",
     "coordinates": [
       [
         [
           77.643495,
           12.960354
         ],
         [
           77.643138,
           12.960391
        ],
         [
           77.642692,
           12.960435
         ],
         [
          77.642605,
           12.960446
         ],
         [
           77.642252,
           12.960486
        ],
         [
          77.641928,
           12.96054
         ],[
           77.64556,
           12.972287
         ]
       ]
    ]
   }
 }'
```

-- Query in Step 2:

```
    curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/routes/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "geo_shape": {
      "location": { 
        "shape": { 
          "type":   "circle", 
          "radius": "1km",
          "coordinates": [ 
            77.643495,
          12.960354
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Result:

```
{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

Please point out the fault in above steps.
I'm assuming it should be possible to find nearest geo_shape to given location with ElasticSearch.
Note: Data in queries is different from that in snapshot.
 I've also tried with path.type as linestring, multipoint without success.

Comment: I would use geo_distance query and try to raise the distance, e.g. 10 km. Are there any results? You can refer to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html . I dont know exactly, but if you use a higher distance, the results will be sorted descending by the distance from the origin? So you can simply take the first result, which would be the closest...

Comment: No geo_distance also has not worked as it expects geo_point for comparison whereas I've inserted route points as geo_shape. I will try by inserting route points as geo_point / multipoint later.

Comment: For now as I need a quick PoC, I've switched to MongoDB and used $geoNear operator. It gives nearest route. For step 3, I'll use Google Map roads API

Comment: @RuturajPatil Did you solve this problem by using ES?